# The idea plugin listens to the project running and stopping

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing an idea plug-in, which can monitor the startup and shutdown of the project. The main project type is SpringBoot, and I want to add a javaagent to the project through the plug-in. How do I do it? I can't find relevant documents。

I asked a question in the community, but no one answered me